# Use svg with external font in GIMP

Tags: svg, gimp, google-fonts

I have created this svg with an external font, that part of the SVG looks like this:

```
<defs>
  <style type="text/css">@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo|Gloria+Hallelujah|Rokkitt|Shadows+Into+Light|Signika&gt;</style>
</defs>
```

In Chrome this works nice, but when I try to load the svg into GIMP the font is missing. Is there a way for GIMP to render the google fonts?

Complete test svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
      <style type="text/css">@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cairo|Gloria+Hallelujah|Rokkitt|Shadows+Into+Light|Signika&gt;</style>

  </defs>
  <style>
     text {
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family: Shadows Into Light;
     }
  </style>

  <text x="20" y="35"><tspan>Test</tspan></text>
</svg>
```

Update: For the SVG to work in Gimp or Inkscape:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <style type="text/css">
      <![CDATA[
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Shadows Into Light';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: normal;
          src: local('Shadows Into Light'), local('ShadowsIntoLight'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/shadowsintolight/v3/clhLqOv7MXn459PTh0gXYHW1xglZCgocDnD_teV2lMU.woff') format('woff');
        }

        text {
          font-size: 30px;
          font-family: Shadows Into Light;
        }
      ]]>
    </style>
  </defs>

  <text x="20" y="35"><tspan>Test</tspan></text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem goes further than external Google fonts:

1) Gimp (or whatever SVG parser it uses) is picky about the syntax (normally the style should be in CDATA)

2) Even with the CDATA fix (that at least stop nasty messages in the Gimp console), Gimp won't abide to the `font-family` style, even for fonts installed system-wide.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Is there an other tool that you recommend for editing or converting to other formats?

Comment: If you want to edit SVG files, the canonical FOSS tool is Inkscape. It won't download external fonts but you can download and install the font locally first, it will abide to the CSS style. I fyou want to edit the bitmap in Gimp, render in Inkscape, export to PNG and dot eh PNG in Gimp (unless there is a way in Inkscape to convert the text to vectors).

Comment: So I worked it out with all the hints given. First I added the `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` (see post) then I downloaded the google font and install it using Font Book. This way Gimp picked it up automatically. I was now able to export the svg in any size to png, very nice :) Inkscape didn't pick up the font, because you have to do a small [adjustment](https://eastmanreference.com/fix-missing-fonts-in-inkscape-on-mac). Cheers

Comment: Glad it worked for you, because downloading the font didn't work for me (nor did using any existing local fonts...)